# Query on Deployment of Record Types

Tags: deployment, record-type

I created one new record type each for 4 custom objects which already have 2 existing record types. While deploying the newly created record types, please suggest what all its related components(page layouts/profiles etc.) to be included for deployment to make sure that there is no manual inclusion of them in the destination sandbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following Consideration:

1)Record Types + Profiles migration will do the trick

2)Layouts

3)you must also deploy all fields that the Record Type references

4)Finally,you have to assign PickList Values manually for each RecordTypes before deploying.

Comment: Thanks Ashish for your response. Can you please elaborate last two points..